# Do Hask or Agda have equalisers?

Tags: haskell, agda, category-theory

I was somewhat undecided as to whether this was a math.SE question or an SO one, but I suspect that mathematicians in general are fairly unlikely to know or care much about this category in particular, whereas Haskell programmers might well do.

So, we know that **Hask** has products, more or less (I'm working with idealised-Hask, here, of course). I'm interested in whether or not it has equalisers (in which case it would have all finite limits).

Intuitively it seems not, since you can't do separation like you can on sets, and so subobjects seem hard to construct in general. But for any specific case you'd like to come up with, it seems like you'd be able to hack it by working out the equaliser in **Set** and counting it (since after all, every Haskell type is countable and every countable set is isomorphic either to a finite type or the naturals, both of which Haskell has). So I can't see how I'd go about finding a counterexample.

Now, Agda seems a bit more promising: there it *is* relatively easy to form subobjects. Is the obvious sigma type `Σ A (λ x → f x == g x)` an equaliser? If the details don't work, is it *morally* an equaliser?

Comment: Well, your idea about working it out in Set and counting it would only work if the equalizer were recursively enumerable... otherwise it's not isomorphic to Nat in Hask.

Comment: Does anyone have an example of an equalizer that wouldn't be recursively enumerable?  I feel like I've been close to finding one but I haven't.

Comment: Is it event possible for a Haskell type not not be recursively enumerable?  It seems like there shouldn't be...  I would imagine if one could find an equalizer not recursively enumerable then you would be done (my examples below are recursively enumerable, just not decidable).  The real issue that reasoning in Set doesn't work is because the arrows are different.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**tl;dr the proposed candidate is not quite an equaliser, but its irrelevant counterpart is**

The candidate for an equaliser in Agda looks good. So let's just try it. We'll need some basic kit. Here are my refusenik ASCII dependent pair type and homogeneous intensional equality.

```
record Sg (S : Set)(T : S -> Set) : Set where
  constructor _,_
  field
    fst : S
    snd : T fst
open Sg

data _==_ {X : Set}(x : X) : X -> Set where
  refl : x == x
```

Here's your candidate for an equaliser for two functions

```
Q : {S T : Set}(f g : S -> T) -> Set
Q {S}{T} f g = Sg S \ s -> f s == g s
```

with the `fst` projection sending `Q f g` into `S`.

What it says: an element of `Q f g` is an element `s` of the source type, together with a proof that `f s == g s`. But is this an equaliser? Let's try to make it so.

To say what an equaliser is, I should define function composition.

```
_o_ : {R S T : Set} -> (S -> T) -> (R -> S) -> R -> T
(f o g) x = f (g x)
```

So now I need to show that any `h : R -> S` which identifies `f o h` and `g o h` must factor through the candidate `fst : Q f g -> S`. I need to deliver both the other component, `u : R -> Q f g` and the proof that indeed `h` factors as `fst o u`. Here's the picture: `(Q f g , fst)` is an equalizer if whenever the diagram commutes without `u`, there is a unique way to add `u` with the diagram still commuting.

[image: equaliser diagram]

Here goes existence of the mediating `u`.

```
mediator : {R S T : Set}(f g : S -> T)(h : R -> S) ->
           (q : (f o h) == (g o h)) ->
           Sg (R -> Q f g) \ u -> h == (fst o u)
```

Clearly, I should pick the same element of `S` that `h` picks.

```
mediator f g h q = (\ r -> (h r , ?0)) , ?1
```

leaving me with two proof obligations

```
?0 : f (h r) == g (h r)
?1 : h == (\ r -> h r)
```

Now, `?1` can just be `refl` as Agda's definitional equality has the eta-law for functions. For `?0`, we are blessed by `q`. Equal functions respect application

```
funq : {S T : Set}{f g : S -> T} -> f == g -> (s : S) -> f s == g s
funq refl s = refl
```

so we may take `?0 = funq q r`.

But let us not celebrate prematurely, for the existence of a mediating morphism is not sufficient. We require also its uniqueness. And here the wheel is likely to go wonky, because `==` is *intensional*, so uniqueness means there's only ever one way to *implement* the mediating map. But then, our assumptions are also intensional...

Here's our proof obligation. We must show that any other mediating morphism is equal to the one chosen by `mediator`.

```
mediatorUnique :
  {R S T : Set}(f g : S -> T)(h : R -> S) ->
  (qh : (f o h) == (g o h)) ->
  (m : R -> Q f g) ->
  (qm : h == (fst o m)) ->
  m == fst (mediator f g h qh)
```

We can immediately substitute via `qm` and get

```
mediatorUnique f g .(fst o m) qh m refl = ?

? :  m == (\ r -> (fst (m r) , funq qh r))
```

which looks good, because Agda has eta laws for records, so we know that

```
m == (\ r -> (fst (m r) , snd (m r)))
```

but when we try to make `? = refl`, we get the complaint

```
snd (m _) != funq qh _ of type f (fst (m _)) == g (fst (m _))
```

which is annoying, because identity proofs are unique (in the standard configuration). Now, you can get out of this by postulating extensionality and using a few other facts about equality

```
postulate ext : {S T : Set}{f g : S -> T} -> ((s : S) -> f s == g s) -> f == g

sndq : {S : Set}{T : S -> Set}{s : S}{t t' : T s} ->
       t == t' -> _==_ {Sg S T} (s , t) (s , t')
sndq refl = refl

uip : {X : Set}{x y : X}{q q' : x == y} -> q == q'
uip {q = refl}{q' = refl} = refl

? = ext (\ s -> sndq uip)
```

but that's overkill, because the only problem is the annoying equality proof mismatch: the computable parts of the implementations match on the nose. So the fix is to work with *irrelevance*. I replace `Sg` by the `Ex`istential quantifier, whose second component is marked as irrelevant with a dot. Now it matters not which proof we use that the witness is good.

```
record Ex (S : Set)(T : S -> Set) : Set where
  constructor _,_
  field
    fst : S
    .snd : T fst
open Ex
```

and the new candidate equaliser is

```
Q : {S T : Set}(f g : S -> T) -> Set
Q {S}{T} f g = Ex S \ s -> f s == g s
```

The entire construction goes through as before, except that in the last obligation

```
? = refl
```

is accepted!

So yes, even in the intensional setting, eta laws and the ability to mark fields as irrelevant give us equalisers.

**No undecidable typechecking was involved in this construction.**

Answer (score 14):

### Hask

Hask doesn't have equalizers.  An important thing to remember is that thinking about a type (or the objects in any category) and their isomorphism classes really requires thinking about the arrows.  What you say about the underlying sets is true, but types with isomorphic underlying sets certainly aren't necessarily isomorphic.  One difference between Hask and Set as that Hask's arrows must be computable, and in fact for idealized Hask, they must be total.

I spent a while trying to come up with a real defensible counterexample, and found some references suggesting it cannot be done, but without proofs.  However, I do have some "moral" counterexamples if you will; I cannot prove that no equalizer exists in Haskell, but it certainly seems impossible!

### Example 1

```
f, g: ([Int], Int) -> Int

f (p,v) = treat p as a polynomial with given coefficients, and evaluate p(v).
g _ = 0
```

The equalizer "should" be the type of all pairs (p,n) where p(n) = 0, along with a function injecting these pairs into ([Int], Int).  By Hilbert's 10th problem, this set is undecidable.  It seems to me that this should exclude the possibility of it being a Haskell type, but I can't prove that (is it possible that there's some bizarre way to construct this type that nobody has discovered?).  It maybe I haven't connected a dot or two -- perhaps proving this is impossible isn't hard?

### Example 2

Say you have a programing language.  You have a compiler that takes the source code and an input and produces a function, for which the fixed point of the function is the output.  (While we don't have compilers like this, specifying semantics sort of like this isn't unheard of).  So, you have

```
compiler : String -> Int -> (Int -> Int)
```

(Un)curry that into a function

```
compiler' : (String, Int, Int) -> Int
```

and add a function

```
id' : (String, Int, Int) -> Int
id' (_,_,x) = x
```

Then the equalizer of compiler', id' would be the collection of triplets of source program, input, output -- and this is uncomputable because the programing language is fully general.

### More Examples

Pick your favorite undecidable problem: it generally involves deciding if an object is the member of some set.  You often have a total function that can be used to check this property for a particular object.  You can use this function to create an equalizer where the type should be all the items in your undecidable set.  That's where the first two examples came from, and there are tons more.

### Agda

I'm not as familiar with Agda.  My intuition is that your sigma-type should be an equalizer: you can write the type down, along with the necessary injection function, and it looks like it satisfies the definition entirely.  However, as someone who doesn't use Agda, I don't think I'm really qualified to check the details.

The real practical issue though is that typechecking that sigma type won't always be computable, so it's not always useful to do this.  In all the examples above, you can write down the Sigma type you provided, but you won't be able to readily check if something is a member of that type without a proof.

Incidentally, this is why Haskell shouldn't be able to have equalizers: if it did, the typechecking would be undecidable!  Dependent types is what makes everything tick.  They  should be able to express interesting mathematical structures in its types, while Haskell can't since its typesystem is decideable.  So, I would naturally expect idealized Agda to have all finite limits (I would be disappointed otherwise).  The same goes for other dependently typed languages; Coq, for example, should definitely have all limits.

Comment: "Then the equalizer is the type of all programs that return 0 when run on themselves -- and this is definitely not computable." – I think it is, actually. At stage n, run the first n programs on themselves for n steps. Output any that return 0, and exclude them from future consideration. This ought to give an enumeration of programs that return 0 when run on themselves, no?

Comment: I suppose this presupposes your total language supports a run-for-n-steps algorithm, which you haven't explicitly given me. But it seems like I always ought to be able to construct one (if only by implementing a Haskell interpreter with resource limits!)

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I forgot that I had to restrict it to being a total language.  I'll cook up another example for you ;)

Comment: Okay, I crafted example 2 so that I could use a non-total language.

Comment: I don't understand example 2 now. You say "the fixed point" – do you mean as in `fix`, or what? What if the function has multiple fixed points?

Comment: You've got a function f : Int -> Int.  By "fixed point" I mean the general math definition, a value x such that f(x) = x.  To elaborate: the integers give you an infinite state space.  You can treat any turing machine as a function that maps integers into integers, and does this repeatedly until it "halts".  Then just make sure you flip a bit on every iteration to make sure that the only fixed points are in a halting configuration.  That way, the fixed points of the function correspond to the output of the Turing machine.

Comment: I'm still not convinced you're producing uncomputable rather than merely undecidable sets. Semidecidability is enough to construct the equaliser, so I can still just run through all possibilities in parallel.

Comment: Counterexample to Example 1: http://hpaste.org/83537 . Revoking my upvote because I'm not at all convinced your examples hold up.

Comment: (Warning: don't try to find a large polynomial in that list. The enumeration is a bit sloppy and large numbers show up exponentially late in the ordering. They *are* all there. Eventually.)

Comment: The decidability points here aren't really relevant unless you want your language to prove things for you.